# Janus commercial offerings?

Tags: cassandra, janusgraph

Does IBM, Google, Azure or any other company offer commercial support for JanusGraph?

We are conducting a bakeoff and Janus (aka Titan) is by far superior to Neo4j and DSE Graph and more compliant with Gremlin.

Wondering if there are commercial offerings of Janus (or Titan) out there?

Comment: I am actually surprised to hear Janus is more compliant with Gremlin than DSE Graph, as the people who work on Gremlin wrote DSE Graph and the original Titan. That said I know nothing about this tech, just the history.

Comment: I would say that all three are equally "compliant" with Gremlin as a language. Their implementations may differ, but that is the nature of Apache TinkerPop - it provides interfaces and different graph systems showcase their abilities through those interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

From the JanusGraph docs, https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/, "The following companies offer JanusGraph hosted as-a-service:

IBM

https://www.compose.com/databases/janusgraph"